# Run Spring application in WebSphere 7.0

Tags: java, spring, websphere

I deploy spring application on Websphere 7.0, add

> -javaagent:C:\Users\whatever.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-instrument\3.2.5.RELEASE\spring-instrument-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

to generic VM options on server, check - this jar-file exists, but i still get Exception:

> Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See
>   Spring documentation

Comment: Why using -javaagent option not affect and i still get error? Need i add additional options?